# Why won't my image show on my gui "smiling.jpg"

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

why can't i see the image in the gui "smiling.jpg" it's just a blank

```
    JLabel label;
    JFrame frame;
    
    mousedemo(){
        
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("smiling.jpg"));
            label.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
        
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(840, 840);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addMouseListener(this);
            frame.add(label);
```

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` expects a file on the file system.  In your case, the file is expected to be in the same location as the program is executed.  You can use something like `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` to display what that location is.  In additional, you should call `setVisible` last, after you've added the label to the UI.  These are rather common issues and are asked quite often

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.